# How to compile these 2 java files correctly?

Tags: java, compilation

I'm following the steps [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/solutions/ScreenGrabber.html), it's basically :

1. Compile the DataSource and LiveStream classes:
     javac -d . DataSource.java LiveStream.java
2. Run using JMStudio:
     java JMStudio screen://0,0,160,120/10

But when I compile them, got lots of errors like `javax.media` doesn't exist and so on.

Here's the directory structure:

```
D:\>dir

2010-06-11  22:25    <DIR>          .
2010-06-11  22:25    <DIR>          ..
2010-06-11  22:25             3,730 DataSource.java
2010-06-11  22:25             6,860 LiveStream.java
```

Can someone give more detailed steps how to set up the environment correctly to compile correctly?

**UPDATE**

Output of `java -version`:

```
java version "1.6.0_02"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_02-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.6.0_02-b06, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the [Java Media Framework](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/) jar in your classpath.  The easiest way to do this is on the command line:

```
javac -cp path/to/jmf.jar -d . DataSource.java LiveStream.java
```

Comment: @user198729: The JMF Customizer should generate a jar file when you run it, or so I recall.  It's been a while since I used JMF.

Comment: Is it the best choice to implement system desktop and audio recording using java in your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

You're either missing a `CLASSPATH` environment variable, or using an incorrect version of java.

You can download `jmf.jar` [there](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/download.html).

**UPDATE**
To set the classpath:

```
set CLASSPATH=C:\path\to\jmf.jar;%CLASSPATH%
javac -d . DataSource.java LiveStream.java
```

or as the R. Bemrose suggested:

```
javac -cp C:\path\to\jmf.jar -d . DataSource.java LiveStream.java
```

Comment: Most likely classpath, javax.media is part of JMF.